# is it possible to retrieve the refresh token with google oauth2

Tags: python-2.7, oauth, google-oauth

Is it possible to retrieve the `refresh token` from a google account for an application?

I use a google oauth login for my web application. When signing in the first time the `refresh token` is generated. But when something goes wrong or the the program doesnt accept the user, but the user allready signed in the `refresh token` is allready generated. The second time when the user wants to log in the `refresh token` isn't generated. the user must first revoke the web application before the new `refresh token` will be generated.

Is there a way to retrieve the `refresh token` of a user? or maybe even better, kick out the user from the web application?

this is how I get the `refresh token`:

```
        code = request.args.get('code')

        credentials = cls.flow.step2_exchange(code)

        print 'refresh_token:{}'.format(credentials.refresh_token)
```

*I am using Flask*

Comment: Wild guess.  try searching for something called approval_prompt.   If you don't have a refreshtoken you should be able to force it to request a new one from the user. they shouldn't have to revoke access.   Again this is a wild guess I am not a python programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer.

When a user accepts your application a `refresh_token` is generated.
If a user comes back later and hasn't revoked your application, google won't generate another refresh token. You can use `approval_prompt='force'` to force the user to go through the approval prompt.

A user can revoke your application by going to myaccount.google.com > Connected apps and services, selecting your application and revoke.

To revoke the user in your application you can call the following URL:
`'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}'`

example:

```
def revoke(token)
    url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=%s' % token
    h = httplib2.Http()
    return h.request(url, 'GET')[0]
```

the token can be an `access_token` or a `refresh_token`

Comment: see http://geek.bluemangointeractive.com/google-oauth-2-enable-your-application-to-access-data-from-a-google-user/ for an explanation about google oauth 2